# How to use two or multiple xml file in android

Tags: android, xml, listview

i am developing egreeting card application.i have two xml file in first xml file it contain buttons and list view.when i click on button list will display this list occupy the space of activity.So we cant put any widget in xml file.When click on list item i want to  shows ImageView at same place of list .For  to achieve  this i created another xml and put ImageView inside that.now when i click on ListItem it new xml shows but not in same activiy.how could solve this.i attached full source code here. here is my xml files 
main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/backcolor"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/linearback" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/list_items" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--
   <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/mylayouttwo"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgview1" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="300dp"></ImageView>

   </LinearLayout>
    -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

images.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="@color/backcolor">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="234dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

package com.triumph.greetings;
import android.R.color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class Launch extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    boolean isListVisible=true;
    ImageButton img1,img2;
    ListView lv;
    String[] festivales= new String[]{"Christmas","New year","BirthDay","Easter","Wedding","Valentine","Love","Nature"};
    ImageView img;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        img1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        img2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        img1.setOnClickListener(this);
        img2.setOnClickListener(this);



        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Launch.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,festivales);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int postion,
                    long arg3) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                isListVisible=false;
                Toast.makeText( Launch.this, ((TextView) v).getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //state=true;
                displayimages();
            }

            private void displayimages()
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // fetch the images from server and shows in GridView 
                // call linear layout

                setContentView(R.layout.images);
                img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                img.setBackgroundColor(color.background_light);


            }           
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.imageButton1:
                if(isListVisible)
                {
                    lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    isListVisible=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    isListVisible=true;
                }

                break;
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();break;
            case R.id.imageButton2:
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you should use single xml for both list and image and make them visible/invisible/gone (as per your requirement) using setVisibility()

Comment: bt i want to display listview for hole activity.so that i created another xml file

Comment: just make invisible imageview when you display listview and viceversa